# No POST in an AIO system

Tags: boot, post, all-in-one

I recently installed a Linux distro on an All-In-One system, but after seeing the video output was wrong, I googled to find out how to turn off the internal GPU, forgetting this system doesn't have a graphics card, and now it (possibly) doesn't POST.

- I can hear and see the fans operating, but it doesn't display anything and doesn't beep
- I've tried removing the RAM and hard drive, resetting CMOS via its switch, as well as removing the CMOS battery

How do I troubleshoot?

Comment: If resetting BIOS doesn't give image back on the integrated your last chance is to try an external monitor.

Comment: If a motherboard fails POST, it will have a way to identify the problem, either via beeps or LED flashes, however if it doesn't have a GPU and lacks an integrated GPU in the CPU, is a machine even capable of outputting any video output to determine if the BIOS/UEFI is even loading _(without IPMI/IEMI firmware)_? AFAIK, it's not possible to disable a CPU's integrated GPU, even within an unlocked BIOS/UEFI firmware - it can be switched off when booting with discrete graphics [standalone GPU], but can never be flat-out disabled at the user level [AFAIK].

Comment: @JW0914 I suspect the OP disabled the integrated *monitor* but in that case resetting the BIOS should have corrected it. Probably it was just a coincidence and the hardware failed completely.

Comment: @ChanganAuto u mean I should replace it?